# Need excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I need to create an excel formula:
Requirement is that there are three columns say A1,B1,and C1.
Now the formula running on D1 should display the value in C1, but if C1 is blank then it should display the maximum value between A1 and B1.

I know it might be simple for most but I am not at all proficient with EXCEL.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Regards
Bodhi

Thank you for the answers..

now to tweak this a bit.. if all the three columns A1,B1nad C1 are dates and we want the output in D1 ro be in mm/yy format...can that we done with a single formula?

Thank you again for the awesomely speedy response.
Regards
Bodhi

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(C1),MAX(A1,B1), C1 )

Comment: Thanks houssam.. it works .. now to take it a bit further .. say if I am dealing with dates can we ensure that the output is only in mm/yy.

Comment: right click on C1 -> Format Cells ->Custom -> Type:= mm/yyyy

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
=IF(C1="",MAX(A1,B1),C1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check if there is a value in column C, which we can use the ISBLANK() function. the formula below checks the contents of column C. If the falue returned is FALSE it moved on to column B, then column A if column B is blank. If it returns TRUE at any stage then it will grab the contents of the cell and put that in column D. Also if there are no values in all 3 fields it will use the value FALSE.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1),IF(ISBLANK(B1),IF(ISBLANK(A1),"NULL",A1),B1),C1)
```

you can format column D, so that the contents of them cells will be in date format, rather than adding to the formulae to do this. let me know if this works.